# does proportionality always works when analyzing DC motors?

Tags: current, motor, dc-motor

Let's consider this example:
a Trolley that can reach 36kmph when there is lite traffic with a current of 700A, and when the traffic gets heavy, the speed decrease to 20kmph.
now i want to deduct the current form these information.

so my question is, would proportionality rules always apply for these kinds of analysis.
for example the current would be: I2 = (20/36)*700 = 389A

the problem with this approach, is that it contradicts with how DC motors work, which is when speed decreases, the current increases

Comment: Current is not proportional to speed of motor. Even if it was, your model is way to oversimplified. So no, it doesn't work.

Comment: "when the traffic gets heavy, the speed decrease to 20kmph" - Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motor voltage or EMF is proportional only if no load. as RPM/V or kV/RPM

Motor current is proportional to torque.

Thus current will rise as load increases and voltage drops from a light load condition. Overall , power drain increases, so you can presume current rise is faster than voltage sag up to some point.

Answer (score 0):

> it contradicts with how DC motors work, which is when speed decreases, the current increases

That is only the case for a DC motor that is driven with a constant voltage (and either a constant or increasing field; I assume you're thinking about permanent-magnet motors with constant field).

> would proportionality rules always apply for these kinds of analysis. for example the current would be: I2 = (20/36)*700 = 389A

No.  Assuming you're thinking about permanent-magnet motors, motor current is more or less proportional to the motor torque, plus some losses.  The torque needed to drive your streetcar is going to depend on speed in a complicated way; there will certainly be components that are proportional to speed, but there will also be constant components, and components that depend on speed squared or have more complicated relationships to speed.

So, basically, it ain't that simple, and determining just what actually happens is difficult to deduce from first principles.

Answer (score 0):

Current is proportional to torque, if you slow a motor by increasing the mechanical load then current will increase.

Voltage is mostly proportional to speed (but you have to include the current through the motors internal resistance which resistance reduces the voltage available for speed.

Your trolley problem is under-specified, the current will be whatever the trolley driver deems necessary at any instant.
if heavy traffic means more passengers then current goes up. if it means lighter acceleration it goes down.

For the same mechanical load you have the same current, so hill-climbs at either speed will take the same current.